# Where did the Luigi task go?

Tags: python, hadoop, luigi

First time into the realm of Luigi (and Python!) and have some questions.  Relevant code is:

```
from Database import Database
import luigi

class bbSanityCheck(luigi.Task):

  conn = luigi.Parameter()
  date = luigi.Parameter()
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(bbSanityCheck, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.has_run = False

  def run(self):
    print "Entering run of bb sanity check"
    # DB STUFF HERE THAT DOESN"T MATTER
   print "Are we in la-la land?"

  def complete(self):
    print "BB Sanity check being asked for completeness: " , self.has_run
    return self.has_run

class Pipeline(luigi.Task):
  date = luigi.DateParameter()

  def requires(self):
    db = Database('cbs')
    self.conn = db.connect()
    print "I'm about to yield!"
    return bbSanityCheck(conn = self.conn, date = self.date)


  def run(self):
    print "Hello World"
    self.conn.query("""SELECT * 
              FROM log_blackbook""")
    result = conn.store_result()

    print result.fetch_row()

  def complete(self):
    return False

if __name__=='__main__':
  luigi.run()
```

Output is here (with relevant DB returns removed 'cause):

```
DEBUG: Checking if Pipeline(date=2013-03-03) is complete
I'm about to yield!
INFO: Scheduled Pipeline(date=2013-03-03)
I'm about to yield!
DEBUG: Checking if bbSanityCheck(conn=<_mysql.connection open to 'sas1.rad.wc.truecarcorp.com' at 223f050>, date=2013-03-03) is complete
BB Sanity check being asked for completeness:  False
INFO: Scheduled bbSanityCheck(conn=<_mysql.connection open to 'sas1.rad.wc.truecarcorp.com' at 223f050>, date=2013-03-03)
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 2
INFO: [pid 5150] Running   bbSanityCheck(conn=<_mysql.connection open to 'sas1.rad.wc.truecarcorp.com' at 223f050>, date=2013-03-03)
Entering run of bb sanity check
Are we in la-la land?
INFO: [pid 5150] Done      bbSanityCheck(conn=<_mysql.connection open to 'sas1.rad.wc.truecarcorp.com' at 223f050>, date=2013-03-03)
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
INFO: Done
INFO: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO: There are 1 pending tasks possibly being run by other workers
INFO: Worker was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
```

So the questions:

1.) Why does "I'm about to yield" get printed twice?

2.) Why is "hello world" never printed?

3.) What is the "1 pending tasks possibly run by other workers"?

I prefer super-ultra clean output because it is way easier to maintain.  I'm hoping I can get these warning equivalents ironed out.

I've also noted that requires either "yield" or "return item, item2, item3".  I've read about yield and understand it.  What I don't get is which convention is considered superior here or if their are subtle differences that I being new to the language am not getting.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're misunderstanding how luigi works in general.

(1) Hmm.. not sure about that. It looks more like an issue with printing the same thing in both INFO and DEBUG to me

(2)
So, you're trying to run Pipeline which depends on bbSanityCheck to run. bbSanityCheck.complete() never returns True because you never set has_run to True in bbSanityCheck. So the Pipeline task can *never* run and output hello world, because its dependencies are never complete.

(3) That's probably because you have this pending task(it's actually Pipeline). But Luigi understands it is impossible for it to run and shuts down.

I would personally not use has_run as a way to check if a task has run, but instead check for the existence of the result of this job. Ie, if this job does sth to the database then, complete() should check that the expected contents are there.

Comment: So giving you a vote up...but I can't check it because I am not longer working with that project and don't have access to the omitted code to double check.